# Set of prime numbers $q$ such that $\sum\limits_{p\leq\sqrt{q}}p=\pi(q)$, where $p$ are prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

The question is: does the set of prime numbers $q$ such that $\sum\limits_{p\leq\sqrt{q}}p=\pi(q)$, where $p$ are prime numbers, contain infinitely many elements? You can find the first elements here (http://oeis.org/A329403). Any insight on this would be welcomed.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

Comment: This question [has already been posted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/381937/30186) by the same author before, though it has been deleted and reposted an hour ago. This is an unacceptable abuse of the site's functions.

Comment: I don't see the point to restrict to $q$ prime and $\ge$ is more natural than $=$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999435/set-of-prime-numbers-q-such-that-sum-limits-p-leq-sqrtqp-piq

Comment: @Wojowu, I did not know that this was not acceptable. I have deleted the other post because I received negative feedback regarding the post content and advice to express it in other way, so I have deleted it and posted this new one, which is the same as the old but better expressed, and without the negative comments regarding post content and expression. If it is not correct to do so, I apologize, and if some administrator thinks that is not appropriate I will accept their suggestions / actions

Comment: The content of the question is almost identical, I don't see how it is "better expressed".

Comment: @reuns: I may have lost a factor of 2. I rely on PNT and on the Bach and Shallit asymptotic as given at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html

Comment: $\sum_{p\le y} p \sim \sum_{n\le y} \frac{n}{\log n}\sim \frac{y^2}{2\log y}$ so $\sum_{p\le x^{1/2}} p \sim \frac{x}{\log x}\sim \pi(x)$. See the MSE post (if I'm not wrong) that $\pi(x)-\sum_{p\le x^{1/2}} p$ changes of sign infinitely many times depends on the RH @MaxAlekseyev

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "administrator", but MathOverflow, like Stackexchange sites generally, is community moderated. We have 'official' moderators with superpowers for various purposes, but they aren't going to step in to suggest improvements _in their capacity as mods,_ here. More specific to the current issue, though, the system expects people to edit their questions into a better shape, rather than self-delete and start again. If people see deletions and re-asking of questions, then it raises concerns, because this is a strategy that various bad actors have used in the past.

Comment: Looking at the old question, which is almost identical to this one, Will Sawin gave some good advice that could have been used to improve that one, and make any other edits you needed at the same time (I notice that $\lt$ became $\leq$ in this version), rather than asking a new question. I also note that you got a reasonably substantial answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999435/set-of-prime-numbers-q-such-that-sum-limits-p-leq-sqrtqp-piq, where Conjecture 2 looks awfully like the above question.

Comment: And the answer there says your Conjecture 2 is false, assuming the Riemann Hypothesis. It's a bold move asking people to prove things that disprove such a famous conjecture that is widely believed to be true.

Comment: @reuns: I think that $\pi(x)-\sum_{p\le x^{1/2}} p$ changes sign infinitely often, regardless of the Riemann Hypothesis. See my post below.

Comment: @GHfromMO Right, I overlooked that $P(2s-1)$ has a bunch of complex singularities on $\Re(s)=3/4$, thank you

Comment: @reuns: On the other hand your analysis seems more direct, hence more to the point.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, thanks for your feedback. It is true that @_reuns gave a very nice response at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999435/set-of-prime-numbers-q-such-that-sum-limits-p-leq-sqrtqp-piq, but as it was the only one, and I am afraid that I am an amateur mathematician with no deep knowledge in calculus, I wanted some kind of double check. As it seems, at least there is a bit of debate regarding it, so it has been worthy (even if it has not been in the more appropriate way, and I apologize) to recycle the older post to draw attention.

Comment: @JuanMoreno In general, it's better to revise questions than to repost them.  I won't delete this one since it has an answer below.  If you revise your post and the comments are no longer relevant, you can flag them for deletion as "no longer needed."

Comment: @BenWebster thanks for your comment; I will proceed as you suggest

Comment: @JuanMoreno I'm glad you got a satisfactory answer :-)

Comment: _@David Roberts thanks! I am very happy too, it has been two years since I had this conjecture in mind, and finally is proved :) It is a good motivation to continue researching and studying! At the moment I was uncapable of proving it, I am very thankful of @GH from MO, _@Will Sawin and _@reuns help, and let us hope that in some time I will be able to understand fully the proof and the implications of the proved conjecture ;-)

Comment: Please mention at http://oeis.org/A329403 that the conjecture is proven now, and please link this page. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @GH from MO I proposed the changes you mention two days ago, it is pending of approval; I guess in few days it will be updated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nice question! The answer is affirmative. If $\sigma(x)$ denotes the sum of primes up to $\sqrt{x}$, then it suffices to show that $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)$ changes sign infinitely often, because
$$\pi(x)-\sigma(x)<0<\pi(x+1)-\sigma(x+1)$$
never holds. I thank Juan Moreno and Will Sawin for this simple but crucial observation. My streamlined argument below owes to reuns' ideas as well.

Let us introduce the notation
$$\pi(x)=\mathrm{li}(x)-\mathrm{li}(1)+\rho(x),$$
then we get
\begin{align*}\sigma(x)
&=\int_1^\sqrt{x}t\,d\pi(t)\\
&=\int_1^\sqrt{x}\frac{t\,dt}{\log t}+\int_1^\sqrt{x} t\ d\rho(t)\\
&=\int_1^x\frac{du}{\log u}+\int_1^\sqrt{x} t\ d\rho(t)\\
&=\mathrm{li}(x)-\mathrm{li}(1)+\int_1^\sqrt{x} t\ d\rho(t).
\end{align*}
So the difference $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)$ can be directly estimated by the error term in the prime number theorem. We can analyze this difference further by considering the Mellin transform
$$\int_1^\infty x^{-s}\ d(\pi(x)-\sigma(x))=\int_1^\infty(x^{-s}-x^{1-2s})\ d\rho(x).$$
We shall only need to look at the left-hand side. Integrating by parts, we see that it is holomorphic in a region containing the half-plane $\Re(s)>1$ and the half-line $s>2/3$. In fact, in this region, the left-hand side equals
$$\log\zeta(s)-\log\zeta(2s-1)+\frac{1}{2}\log\zeta(4s-2)+f(s),\tag{$\ast$}$$
where $f(s)$ is holomorphic for $\Re(s)>2/3$.
As in the proof of Theorem 15.2 in Montgomery-Vaughan: Multiplicative number theory I, this eventually yields that
$$\pi(x)-\sigma(x)=\Omega_\pm(x^c)\quad\text{for any}\quad c<3/4.$$
Indeed, let us assume that this bound fails for some $c<3/4$. Without loss of generality, $c>2/3$. Then, by Landau's lemma (which is Lemma 15.1 in the same book), $(\ast)$ is holomorphic in the half-plane $\Re(s)>c$. However, this is easily seen to be false, and we are done.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Then, as $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)$ changes sign infinitely often, can we affirm that $\pi(x)=\sigma(x)$ infinitely many times? Logic would invite to think so, as there can be no "leaps" from $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)=1$ to  $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)=-1$, and viceversa. If this is so, then the set has infinitely many elements, and the question is answered.

Comment: consider that $\pi(x)$ increases $1$ by $1$. Thus, at least every sign changing from $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)<0$ to $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)>0$ would necessarily pass through the equality $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)=0$. As this happens infinitely many times, hence my conclusion. Is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: the leap you mention at a prime square $x$ would imply (if any) a change of sign from $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)>0$ to $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)<0$, and you are right that this would not imply equality; however, I am referring to the other change of sign, from $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)<0$ to $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)>0$  in which can not be involved any prime square $x$, at least as I see it.

Comment: I think Juan Moreno is right here - every time $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)$ changes from negative to positive, it must pass through $0$, because it is impossible to have $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)< 0$ and $\pi(x+1) -\sigma(x+1)>0$.

Comment: @JuanMoreno: You are right! I will update my post.

Comment: @WillSawin: Thanks for clarifying. I guess Landau's lemma (or the cold front) killed my brain for today.

Comment: @GHfromMO  I do not know if it is worthy to publish some joint paper of this question; I leave it to your jugdment, since you are more experienced than me and you have given the proof. I tried to contact you but apparently is not possible here do to anonymity reasons

Comment: @JuanMoreno: I would not publish it, because: (1) I don't see any applications, (2) the techniques are standard, (3) it would only make a very short paper. But: you can go ahead by referencing this page, and I am sure *some journal* would take it. It would be more important though, in my opinion, that you understand the mathematics behind the proof. For this it suffices to read a book in complex analysis and a book in analytic number theory. If you have a solid background in calculus, then you can do this in 1-2 years. In fact one should not publish anything that one does not understand fully.

Comment: @GHfromMO thanks for your evaluation and your advice. I will proceed as you recommend, and in few years I hope to be able to make some nice proofs as this one! ;)

Comment: @GHfromMO I can read in OEIS: "Conjecture: there exist infinitely many such prime numbers..." So, why don't you publish this? You just proved a conjecture. It may be a short and standard proof as you say, but it is a proof. Why does it have to be long and non-standard? Of course it is your choice, as it is your proof.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas: I regard this result more like a fun exercise than an important theorem. Of course, there is a certain charm to it, but this is due to Juan Moreno, not me. Perhaps, when I get old, I will publish a paper containing my favorite results at MathOverflow. Results like this one or the following one: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341845/when-does-axybyzczx-represent-all-integers/341858#341858

Comment: That would be a great idea GH, and I can't wait to read such a paper even though I can't wish you to get old too fast of course.

Comment: Why isn't it $\sigma(x) = \sqrt{x}(li(\sqrt{x}) - li(1)) -\int_1^{\sqrt{x}} t d \rho(t)$?

Comment: @LorenoHeer: I added more detail. See the third display in my post. The point is that the measure $d\pi(t)$ decomposes as the sum of $d\mathrm{li(t)}=dt/\log t$ and $d\rho(t)$.

Comment: @GHfromMO Perfect, thanks. Now I understand it.