# Some pending questions about $\sum_{p\leq\sqrt{n}}p=\pi(n)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, limits-and-convergence

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/391630/172800) it was showed that $S(n)\sim  \pi(n)$, where $S(n)=\sum_{p\leq\sqrt{n}}p$, $p$ refers to prime numbers, and $\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function. [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/383610/172800) it was proved that $S(n)=\pi(n)$ for infinitely many values of $n$.

Define now $\tau(n)$ as the function that counts the number of values for which $S(x)=\pi(x)$, for $x$ less than or equal to $n$. For instance, $\tau(1)=1$, as $S(1)=\pi(1)=0$; and the first values of $\tau(n)$ are ${1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,...}$.

The question now is: is provable that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\tau(n)}{n}=0$$

My first empirical estimations seem to point to the above limit, having verified until $\tau(81628)=72$. However, I do not know how to prove it. Any help would be welcomed.

Other hand, if we define $\theta(n)$ as the function that counts the number of sums of $1, 2,\dots, n$ primes that are $S(m)$ for some $m$ such that $S(m)=\pi(m)$, we have that it is much more dense. As per empirirical verification, $\theta(61)=12$, meaning that of the 61 sums of $1,2,...,61$ first primes, $12$ are such that are $S(m)$ for some $m$ such that $S(m)=\pi(m)$. I would conjecture that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\theta(n)}{n}=0$ too, but again I have no clue of how to prove it.

Finally, as intriguing observations, $(i) \space\pi\left(p_{k}^{2}\right)\neq\sum_{i=1}^{k}p_{i}$ excepting $p_1=2$ (already mentioned in the first link cited, still unproved), and $(ii)\space$ Seems that every prime number for which $S(n)=\pi(n)$ has terminations $1$ or $9$. However, I have no idea why this could be happening. Any hint would be welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "termination" meaning "last digit when written in base ten"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, that is the meaning of "termination" in this case

Comment: The observation about the final digit seems a coincidence of small numbers. For example (the computer says that) $S(n)=\pi(n)$ for the primes $219647$ (first hit with a prime of last digit $7$), or 
$1263173$ (first hit with last digit $3$), among others.

Comment: The first conjecture (on limit $0$) is of course entirely plausible, simply since, whenever $\pi(n)=S(n)$, this equality tends to change after roughly $\log(n)$ numbers, but now, since $S(n)$ grows in large jumps whereas $\pi(n)$ grows in steps of $1$, one needs to find at least another $\sqrt{n}$ primes, which trivially takes at least $\sqrt{n}$ numbers. This would make for a strict proof if one could show that there is (asymptotically) always a prime in $[n, n+n^{\epsilon}]$ for some $\epsilon<1/2$, but this might be too tough.

Comment: @JoachimKönig thanks for your comments! Happy to know that the digits observation was a coincidence, I did not understand why was happening...

Comment: The best which is known is that there exist primes between $n$ and $n+Cn^{.525}$. However, one could get away with proving something weaker: like there doesn’t exist $N^{.4}$ distinct primes less than $N$ whose prime gap has length $>N^{.49}$.

Comment: Think in this way,