# Is integer circuit membership undecidable?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, computational-complexity, diophantine-equations

According to wikipedia 
[integer circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_circuit) 
in its simplest form is succinct representation of multivariate polynomial with
integer coefficients. Decidability if an integer is represented by the integer circuit is an open problem.

Working only with integer circuits with gates $\times,+,-$ we got an
argument that it is undecidable to check if integer is represented
by the circuit.

Take undecidable diophantine equation $f(x_i)=0$.
(If you want to work with non-negative solution, replace each
$x_i$ with the sum of squares of four new variables).

Let $C_f$ be the integer circuit which computes $f$.

$C_f$ represents $0$ if $f(x_i)=0$ has a solution and by
construction this is undecidable.

> Does this prove integer circuit membership is undecidable?

(We don't use gates about set union, intersection and complement).

Comment: Does the Wikipedia table on complexity scale with the cardinality of the set from which you draw your input integer? With the proof above you are asking if there is *any* integer solution; if you ask instead if there’s a solution from within a finite set, then maybe you get the complexity results listed in Wikipedia?

Comment: Maybe not.  Travers [linked](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397506005585?via%3Dihub) in Wikipedia indicates that the inputs are members of the power set of $\mathbb{Z}$; I believe the size of the input is related to the complexity of the circuit evaluating $C_f$ and not of the elements of the power set of  $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MarkS Thanks. Does size matter for decidability? The size maybe horribly large, but still finite.

Comment: @MarkS Isn't integer circuit Directed Acyclic Graph?

Comment: You misunderstand the definition of the circuit membership problem. The circuits do not compute *integers*, but *sets of integers*. The problem is simply to evaluate the circuit on a *given input*. You are given a circuit, and for each input node, a (finite) set of integers; then each node of the circuit is associated to a specific set of integers, and you are supposed to compute the set associated to the output node. ...

Comment: ...  Now, since the circuits are allowed to use set complement gates, these sets may in general be infinite, and cannot be directly output; for this reason, the problem is actually defined so that you are also given an additional integer $n$ as input, and you are supposed to output if $n$ belongs to the set associated to the output node. This has nothing to do with the range of values attained by the circuit on all possible inputs, as in your construction.

Comment: Small correction: as defined in the paper, the input nodes can be evaluated only by singletons. So, anyway, if your circuit is just an arithmetic circuit not using any set operations, then the task is: given the circuit, integer inputs, and an integer $n$, check if the circuit evaluates to $n$ on the given inputs. This is clearly decidable. More generally, the problem is clearly decidable even if the circuit can use $\cap$ and $\cup$ gates, but no complement gates, as then all the sets are still finite, and can be computed in a bottom-up fashion.

Comment: Here is an interesting twist: if a polynomial $f$ is given by a read-once arithmetic formula (which means that for each $+$ or $\times$ gate in the circuit, the two input nodes compute polynomials in disjoint sets of variables), then we *can* express the set of integers represented by this polynomial by a circuit obtained from the given one just by evaluating each variable to $\mathbb Z$ (which can be constructued as $-(\{0\}\cap\{1\})$). In particular, the circuit membership problem is at least as hard as [solvability of *multilinear* polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/q/338050).

Comment: The last sentence in the previous comment is nonsense, most multilinear polynomials *cannot* be expressed by read-once arithmetic formulas.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks. Is the following problem undecidable:  given arithmetic circuit C and integer n, decide if there is solution x_i such that C(x_i) = n?

Comment: Well that’s just Hilbert’s 10th problem. It’s undecidable, even if for $n=0$.